# Can I ask a question about limits?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I had a test in calculus and I passed but with a really bad grade, mostly because I didn't know all the ways of calculating a limit.

Can I ask : What are all the ways of calculating a limit of a function or a series?

Comment: Certainly you can ask, but you should ask on [the main site](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @robjohn But generally, not on _certain_ function or series.

Comment: @NightRa: I am not sure exactly what you are trying to say. [The FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) says what meta should be used for.

Comment: @robjohn His question is whether it's ok to ask a question to list all the methods which one can use to solve limit problems.

Comment: @NightRa: yes, and I said that that is okay, but to ask on the main site.

Comment: If I saw such a question posted on the main site, I'd probably vote to close it as "too broad". I'd also suggest the author have a look through whatever textbook is handy, where I'd expect may examples to be done, and I'd also suggest the author make an appointment to see the lecturer, who is in the best position to be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

This is a valid question, but since it is a rather open-ended question, it should be tagged [soft-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) or [big-list](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) as well as [limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limit). It should probably also be made [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).